# Error: Invalid arguments while listng nft on auction house

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, auction-house

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to list my NFT on an auction house. The instructions for the listing have been generated accurately, but I'm encountering an error when trying to sign the transaction. It's showing as **Invalid arguments**
I'm signing the transaction using the keypair.

**code:**

```
    console.log(instructions)
    const tx = new Transaction();
    tx.add(...instructions);
    const conn = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

    const signature : any = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(conn, tx, wallet);
    console.log("Transaction confirmed:", signature);
```

**Error:**

```
[
  TransactionInstruction {
    keys: [],
    programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111)] {
      _bn: <BN: 306466fe5211732ffecadba72c39be7bc8ce5bbc5f7126b2c439b3a40000000>
    },
    data: <Buffer 02 80 1a 06 00>
  },
  TransactionInstruction {
    keys: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk)] {
      _bn: <BN: a6593863cba461564eae41373721546eb0151c9308276bbd4ad2a1c3a42107b>
    },
    data: <Buffer 33 e6 85 a4 01 7f 83 ad fe fe ff 00 ca 9a 3b 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
  }
]
Error: Error: Invalid arguments
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this error is extremely vague and doesn't give too much indication of the source of the problem. Can you add some information about the program that you're trying to use and exact way that you've created the instructions?